# Should I flag a new answer to an old question if it doesn't add anything that hasn't been covered by other answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers

I just completed a review ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/10012799), to be specific) and I wasn't sure if I selected the right action. The question is something relatively basic but it's pretty old (from 2011) and very popular. The answer under review is not incorrect, but it is very short and it's an answer that has been repeated several times already (though I doubt it's outright plagiarism; again, the question is pretty basic).

For review purposes, I simply marked it as "No Action Needed". Should I have flagged this answer/downvoted it since it doesn't really add anything new?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is unhelpful, and so you should have downvoted.  Given that you're in a review queue, you should also have strongly considered commenting to explain why the post is problematic.

The only reason to flag such an answer would be if you actually felt that it was plagiarizing other content.