# Review tests of very poor quality

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

Just failed a review test and I really don't like to argue about the process in general.

**But** there are cases when this process simply fails.

**Review test:** [What does void do in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11144825)

**Answer to review:**

> Void means that the method has no return value. If the method returned an String you would write String instead of void.

This answer perfectly explains what was asked for. Never the less it was rejected as being of very poor quality by the review system.

The only thing one could argue is the fact that there are other answers (not shown in the review process btw) which already explained the meaning of void.

In my opinion this does not justify marking the answer as poor quality. And it's simply not a good question for testing the process of users trying to review questions/answers.

If duplicate answers are a real problem that should be solved in the review process then all answers should be shown.

Comment: Please always link to the specific review, not the post reviewed.

Comment: Well, it was a late answer. The audit was justified.

Comment: Added link to audit.

Comment: Since when is being redundant a valid reason for regular users to delete an answer though the review queues? I've only ever heard that it's grounds for a custom moderator flag.

Comment: If a post comes from a new user to an already-accepted, four year old question, then I think it's reasonable to delete the answer if it introduces nothing new. It's better for the community to do this than the moderators, because moderators aren't supposed to judge technical content.

Comment: It is a pervasive problem.  So much so that SE had to provide a feature to stop these kind of useless late answers from no-rep users, a question can be protected to stop them.  Which happened after this post was added, @Mogsdad did so.  Not noticing this when you get audited is indeed a good way to fail the audit.  The "stop, look" part of the recommendation you got.

Comment: Did you notice the comment that said *This answer provides no information that isn't already in other answers.*.  That starts off warning sirens and a blinking red light to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver Does the comment show up when the audit is initially presented to a user? Audits are disguised, no?

Comment: @Louis All comments should show up.  I think the user rep and the votes are the only things that are changed.  Also tags depending on the queue.

Comment: "stop, look" should be expanded to "please, open the question in another tab and glance at the more complete picture before making a choice". I am impressed that reviewers can do it so easily without taking that step first, its like crossing the street without looking both left and right to me.

Comment: I just can repeat myself: If duplicate answers are a real problem that should be solved in the review process then all answers should be shown.

Comment: [I asked a similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308993/should-i-flag-a-new-answer-to-an-old-question-if-it-doesnt-add-anything-that-ha) a while ago and the consensus was that new answers to old questions that don't add any new information are useless. If the answer added new info (for example, if void was used in some new version of Java to mark a method that returned null or something else bizarre), then it would be a completely different story.

Comment: Rule of thumb: No Action Needed is an invalid review action. There is always action needed, be it a downvote, a closevote, a deletevote, a flag, or, failing that, and edit, ore even an upvote! I don't see how you can look at all those options and choose *none of them*, but if you do, press skip instead of NAN.

Comment: The review audit system is broken IMO. Too often the "correct response" is too subjective and thus the post should not have been chosen for an audit. But the audits are chosen algorithmically and are very flawed. Not so much for the First Question and Triage queues, but the Late Answers queue is full of bad choices.

Answer (score 10):

You may think this was a poor quality audit but I think these kinds of audits are perfect.  First we have a very short answer:

> Void means that the method has no return value. If the method returned an String you would write String instead of void.

And the information says that this question has 5 other answers.  To me that makes me want to look closer at it.  Then we had the comment by [Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad):

> This answer provides no information that isn't already in other answers.

Right there I have alarm bells going of and there is a red light blinking on and off.

At this point I would go to the question (the question title is a link to the question and you can open it in a new tab/window).  I would look at it and see what is going on.  In this case the answer wouldn't even show up for you which is a dead giveaway that it was deleted and you have an audit.

This is the kind of behavior the audits are designed to create.  They want to make sure you pay attention to everything.

As as the audit system showing the other answers I do not think that is needed.  In most cases you do not need to see the other answer to make a decision and having them there would clutter the UI.  As I said, you can always open up the question to get more details.

Comment: Then why not include a) A statement that tells us to delete duplicate answers b) a direct link to the full question?

Comment: @maxhb a)  not all duplicate answers should be deleted.  If two people answer the same question at the same time how do you decide who should not have there answer on the question.  The problem in this case is it was a **late** answer that added nothing new.  I think you could agree that we do not want that.  b)There already is a link to the question.  It is the question title.  It is even in blue to show it is a hyperlink.

Comment: My comment about duplicates should be seen in the context of late answers.

Comment: I would add that if this looks like too much work, [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: Using skip is **always** a valid option and not associated to shame.

Comment: "Right there I have alarm bells going of" may be what is going on in your mind but it's nothing that is based on a formal rule or advice given by stackoverflow. It's your interpretation of what's good and right. I share probably most of your interpretation of a good community but those rules are not documented in terms of notices and warnings within the review process. And **that's** what inspired my post. I want a better and cleaner review process.

Comment: @maxhb Well I think it is common sense but my sense can be/is different than yours.  You could always ask a meta Q to see if this situation should be covered in the [faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) and if it should be then we can add it.

Comment: @maxhb But that's *not* what your question has said here.  You've said that that's a quality answer and that no action should be taken on it.  That's just not true.  It's *not* a quality answer, as the audit correctly identified, and you should have acted on that item in a way that reflects that fact.

Comment: @Servy There a re two different definitions of quality answers. a) Answers that the reviewer himself rates as valuable and b) answers that are to be taken as quality answers because they adhere to community/stackoverflow guidelines. The first is something that everybody makes up with himself. The second is something that should be written down and made public. And that's my point: **write this definition down**. We don't want late answers that add nothing new to a question PERIOD